Pandas check if a column has NaT type, unable to find date diff with NaT values
I have StartDate and ExitDate two columns in my dataframe with NaT values in ExitDate column
I wish to create a third column Tenure by finding Difference between ExitDate and StartDate.
StartDate   ExitDate
2022-06-22  2022-08-07
2020-12-28  NaT
2020-12-09  2022-08-04
2019-05-28  2021-10-23
2022-04-27  NaT

The below code gives error
'ufunc 'isnat' is only defined for np.datetime64 and np.timedelta64.'
Although the datatypes are 
 def calculateTenure(row):
    if np.isnat(row.ExitDate):
        ExitDate = pd.datetime.now()
    return (row.ExitDate.year - row.StartDate.year)
        
df['Tenure'] = df.apply(lambda row:calculateTenure(row), axis=1)


The main motive is to check if ExitDate is NaT so that current date can be used for calculation instead.

df['Tenure'] = df['ExitDate'].fillna(pd.Timestamp('now')-df['StartDate'] or to only consider years: df['Tenure'] = df['ExitDate'].fillna(pd.Timestamp('now').dt.year-df['StartDate'].dt.year

@mozway, I do not wish to change the data in the dataframe column, since this is part of a large dataset and exitDate as empty/naT implies that the employee is still part of the organization

I don't understand your comment, you don't have to change the data. The fillna here is done in memory, not assigned back to your original column.

The above suggestion will not change any columns that already exist in the DF. However, since it appears that you will only be calculating dates, it would be better to use the following code : df['Tenure'] = df['ExitDate'].fillna(pd.Timestamp('now').date()) - df['StartDate'] And If you're only counting years, use the previous suggestion
